# Splitting a huge table to small tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 which has 100,000 records .

I need to split it into 10 tables each with 10k records .I don't want to partition the table ,but to split it entirely into 10 different tables .Is it possible ?

Comment: 100000 records is pretty small, why you need to split it into multiple tables? Even 100 million would be ok

Comment: Just for analysis purpose ,is it possible in the first place?

Comment: @Aparma? Of course it's possible, but it will make every query more difficult and less efficient in future, if you need to select from multiple tables.

Comment: Thank you @Tim Schmelter for your comments.I am just splititng for an analysis and not planning to combine the tables at any point in future

Comment: As @TimSchmelter mentioned, 100000 records is small table for sql server. If performance is not an issue, you may consider use view to split it, instead of tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use NTile

```
;with cte
as
(
select ntile(10) over (order by somepk column) as somecol
,* from table 
)
select * from cte where n=1--change n value to get each partition
```

Comment: ntile windowing function was introduced in 2008.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
 INTO new_tb1 
 FROM old_tb
 WHERE row >= 1 AND row<= 10000;

SELECT * 
 INTO new_tb2 
 FROM old_tb
 WHERE row>= 10001 AND row<= 20000;

.
.
.
.
.
SELECT * 
 INTO new_tb3 
 FROM old_tb
 WHERE row>= 90001 AND row<= 100000;
```